# Set the color of each bar in groups of 3

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart

My dataframe has an index with dates and they are in groups of 3. I would like to have Bar 1 to use green, next bar would be red and the next yellow. Then repeat for the next group of three and I just want the date and not the time.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))
df_merged_dates['Percent_move'].plot(kind='bar', color= 'r')
plt.show()
```

[image: screen shot of bar chart]

Answer (score 1):

Do you try:

```
df_merged_dates['Percent_move'].plot(kind='bar', color=['green','red', 'yellow'])
```

Comment: It just comes back with all bars green. What ever the first color is, all bars will be that color only.